# Express d.f. of $Y = \min \{ X1,X2 \}$ in terms of joint d.f.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, order-statistics

**Example:**
Express d.f. of $Y = \min \{X1, X2\}$ in terms of joint d.f.
$$H(x_1,x_2) = P(X_1 \le x_1, X_2 \le x_2)$$

In this exercise, they have an answer $P(Y \le x)= 1 - H(x,\infty) - H(\infty, x) + H(x,x) $ With $$H(x,\infty)=P(X_1 \le x,X_2 \le \infty)=P(X_1 \le x)$$

$$H(\infty ,x)=P(X_2 \le x)$$

---

**What I did:** I thought that it would be more realist to write that:

$$P(Y \le x)= 1 - P(Y >  x)= 1 - P(X_1>x,X_2>x) = 1 - ( 1 - P(X_1 \le x_1, X_2 
\le x_2))$$ and after that I could draw a little line with different postision of $X_1$ $X_2$ and then derive this formula: $P(Y \le x)= 1 + H(x,\infty) + H(\infty, x) - H(x,x) $

---

**I can't see why they have** : $P(Y \le x)= 1 
- H(x,\infty) - H(\infty, x) + H(x,x) $

Comment: In part of your working, you seem to have used that $\color{red}{P(X_1 > x, X_2 > x) = 1-P(X_1 \leq x, X_2\leq x)}$. However, this is not correct since $\{X_1>x, X_2 > x\}$ and $\{ X_1 \leq x, X_2 \leq x\}$ are not actually complementary events.